# BigQuery materialized view - last in group

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

In BigQuery Is it possible to create a materialized view containing the latest row for each group in a base table.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE basetable (
  group_id INT64, timestamp TIMESTAMP, value FLOAT64
);

INSERT INTO basetable (group_id, timestamp, value) VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', 0.1), 
(1, '2020-01-02', 0.2),
(2, '2020-01-02', 0.1),
(2, '2020-01-01', 0.2);
```

```
Base table
+----------+--------------+-------+
| group_id | timestamp    | value |
+----------+--------------+-------+
|    1     | '2020-01-01' |   0.1 |
|    1     | '2020-01-02' |   0.2 |
|    2     | '2020-01-02' |   0.1 |
|    2     | '2020-01-01  |   0.2 |
+----------+--------------+-------+
```

I'd like materialized view to look as follows

```
Materialized view 
+----------+--------------+-------+
| group_id | timestamp    | value |
+----------+--------------+-------+
|    1     | '2020-01-02' |   0.2 |
|    2     | '2020-01-02' |   0.1 |
+----------+--------------+-------+
```

BigQuery materialized views do not support analytical functions or joins.
Is there any other way to create such a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that at most like this, be advised that the result is an Array with one item

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  name as
SELECT group_id,
max(t.timestamp) as timestamp,
ARRAY_AGG(t.value  IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) as value 
FROM table t
group by group_id
```

then you need a view as well

```
create view viewname as
SELECT group_id,timestamp
cast(value [safe_offset(0)] as string) as  value 
FROM materialized_view
```

Comment: I thought that there wouldn't be difference, so I didn't include all the columns I have in the table. Unfortunately, there is difference. Can you think of a way to do it if there're multiple columns I need to get, not only `value`? 
I tried combining them with  TO_JSON_STRING, but this yields an error `Unsupported operator in materialized view: Struct.`

Comment: @JuriKrainjukov at this stage of the Materialized View feature, this is the most you get. You write multiple lines if you need additional coluns, the same line as `value` but a separate line for each additional column

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this, super helpful! For people using DBT, the column mapping can be taken care of using `api.Relation.create` and `adapter.get_columns_in_relation` to get all the columns and then rendering them in a for loop, excluding the column grouped by.

Comment: in case values are a JSON value (since 2022-01), running the offset on the materialized view will incur in a full scan of the JSON instead of taking advantage of the JSON shredding. I didn't find a good solution working with JSONs yet unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single query with exists logic to ensure that the most recent record for each `group_id` is selected:

```
SELECT group_id, timestamp, value
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.group_id = t1.group_id AND t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp);
```

I cannot think of any way to get the result set you want without using either analytic functions or a subquery of some kind.  The above might be the leanest option here, without using analytic functions.

Comment: This query works by itself. Unfortunately, when I create materialize view it shows error `Unsupported operator in materialized view: Limit.`

Comment: Then you may be out of luck.  I can't think of a way to write your view without either using analytic functions or a subquery on the same table.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the same problem and I found that it is now possible to do this with a single query by using the new [MAX_BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#max_by) aggregation. The support for materialized views was added on [Aug 8, 2023](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#August_08_2023).

The final query would be:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test as
SELECT 
  group_id,

  MAX(timestamp) as timestamp,
  MAX_BY(value, timestamp) as value,
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```