# Select last record of each group as a materialised view bq

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

Is it possible to select the record with highest version of each group and store it as a materialised view in bigquery?

Source table

```
version name value
1       a    100
1       b    200
1       c    300
2       c    400
```

I only want to get the last record of each group (group by version), so the output should be like this:

```
version name value
1       a    100
1       b    200
2       c    400
```

Tried with answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/5839247, got an error:
`Materialized views do not support analytic functions or WITH OFFSET.`
Tried with the method from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/5839247, got `Unsupported operator in materialized view: Join.`

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#supported_mvs

Comment: _Last_ - according to what? Highest version number?

Comment: @Yang, seems like you want to deduplicate data, where duplication would be based on a given column (here name) and keep the last on version order? Deduplication is a topic well described in the BQ community.

Comment: @chaiyachaiya the highest version

Comment: @jarlh correct, the highest version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery materialized view - last in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028965/bigquery-materialized-view-last-in-group)

Answer (score 4):

Currently, BigQuery's materialized view doesn't support `OFFSET`.
So, you have to create another view to use `OFFSET`.

#### 1. Create materialized view using `ARRAY_AGG`

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dataset.mv_name AS
SELECT
  name, 
  ARRAY_AGG(version ORDER BY version DESC) as versions,
  ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY version DESC) as values
FROM
  base_table
GROUP BY
  name
```

#### 2. Then, create another view using `OFFSET`

```sql
CREATE VIEW dataset.v_name AS
SELECT
  name,
  versions[OFFSET(0)] as last_version,
  values[OFFSET(0)] as last_value
FROM
  dataset.mv_name
```

Here is [official document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-faq#error_an_internal_error_occurred_and_the_request_could_not_be_completed).

Comment: Is there a better way to do this now that BQ supports (in preview) `inner join` and materialized views without aggregates?

Comment: in case values are a JSON value (since 2022-01), running the offset on the materialized view will incur in a full scan of the JSON instead of taking advantage of the JSON shredding. I didn't find a good solution working with JSONs yet unfortunately