# BigQuery Materialized View Recent record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, materialized-views

I have a table in which data gets appended for the changes. No delete or update, only append is done by a cloud run job.

Base table

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 394 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 939 | 2023-05-01 12:34:56 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 483 345 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 |

I'd like materialized view to look as follows

Materialized view

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 03 478 102 | 2023-05-08 11:09:15 |
| 124 | ABD | 02 848 837 | 2023-05-02 10:45:05 |

I tried the following 2 ways:

1. Creating a subquery to get the latest record.

```
SELECT full_data.* FROM `test_dataset.test_table` AS full_data,
(select Supplier_ID, max(Last_Modified) as SystemModstamp from `test_dataset.test_table`) AS max_data
WHERE full_data.Supplier_ID=max_data.Supplier_ID
AND full_data.Last_Modified=max_data.Last_Modified
```

The query runs but when I try to create a Materialized View by running the below query, I get an error message.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS `test_dataset.test_mv` AS
SELECT full_data.* FROM `test_dataset.test_table` AS full_data,
(select Supplier_ID, max(Last_Modified) as SystemModstamp from `test_dataset.test_table`) AS max_data
WHERE full_data.Supplier_ID=max_data.Supplier_ID
AND full_data.Last_Modified=max_data.Last_Modified
```

```
Incremental materialized view queries may not reference the same table more than once. Table test_dataset.test_table was seen multiple times.
```

Is there any way to overcome this error?

2. I found another solution [BigQuery materialized view - last in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028965/bigquery-materialized-view-last-in-group)
   And I modified the query to get something like below.

```
SELECT Supplier_ID,
max(t.Last_Modified) as Last_Modified,
ARRAY_AGG(t.Supplier_Name IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY t.Last_Modified DESC LIMIT 1) as Supplier_Name, 
ARRAY_AGG(t.Supplier_Contact  IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY t.Last_Modified DESC LIMIT 1) as Supplier_Contact,
FROM `test_dataset.test_table` t
group by Supplier_ID
```

In my real use case I would need to select around 6 such columns. So I would need to use the ARRAY_AGG function for every column with this solution.

Is there any other way to create a Materialized View in BigQuery to fit my purpose?

Comment: Do you have created date as well in your table? if yes then you can use in QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier_id ORDER BY Last_Modified DESC, created_date DESC)=1

Comment: @BihagKashikar I don't have created date in the table. Also using row_number with materiazlied views would give an error saying `Incremental materialized views do not support analytic functions or WITH OFFSET.`

Comment: you can consider writing a plsql block with the query first writing to table with expiration time followed by materialised view reading from table created in first query

Answer (score 0):

One other way to create materialized way would be using begin/end block. see if this suits to your solution.

```
  BEGIN
  --this block create table with a day expiry

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  format (
  """
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `playground.bihag_sandbox_dataset.tmp_supplier_data_latest_record`
  OPTIONS (
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ) AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM `playground.sandbox_dataset.supplier_data_latest_record` tbl1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM `playground.sandbox_dataset.supplier_data_latest_record` tb12 
    WHERE tb12.Supplier_ID = tbl1.Supplier_ID AND tb12.Last_Modified > tbl1.Last_Modified 
    )
  """
);

  --this block creates materialized view with table created above.
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  format (
  """
  CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `playground.sandbox_dataset.mv_supplier_data_latest_record` as (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `playground.sandbox_dataset.tmp_supplier_data_latest_record`
  )
  """
);
END;
```

Comment: So in this case what's the advantage of the mat view if it's the same as the intermediate table? ie, I want mat view so it's updated on new records to the base table. Doing it this way, it seems like the auto-refresh feature wouldn't work?